# Matplotlib plots aren't sharing y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm setting up a graph to compare the accuracy of a couple neural netowrks. I saved the data in a csv but when I create the plot the lines don't share the y-axis

[image of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzQXO.jpg)

The y-axis is also out of order and prints the exact values

I artificially added a 0,0 to both lines which made them share the single point, but they wouldn't overlap otherwise.

note also that the x-axis only has 3 points but this is just an example to show the behavior.

````
def find_max_reached(folder):
    result = 0
    for data in os.listdir(folder):
        with open(os.path.join(folder, data)) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if int(row['examples']) > result:
                    result = int(row['examples'])
    return result

def accuracy_list(csvfile):
    accuracy = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        accuracy.append(row['performance'])
    return accuracy

max_reached = find_max_reached(results_dir)

x = np.linspace(0, max_reached, num=3)

for data in os.listdir(results_dir):
    with open(os.path.join(results_dir, data)) as csvfile:
        plt.plot(x, accuracy_list(csvfile))

plt.show()
path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "results", "graphs")
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
plt.savefig(os.path.join(path, "batch_accuracy_comp.png"))```
````

Comment: Convert your strings to float before plotting them

Comment: Thank you! That totally worked

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)